# ui-router loading html but not showing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a `job` state with `:jobId` parameter.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('employer', {
        url: "/",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: '../partials/employer/employerHome.html',
        controller: 'UserHomeController',
    })
    .state('employer.edit', {
        url: "^/edit",
        templateUrl: '../partials/employer/profile.html',
        controller: 'UserHomeController',
    })
    .state('employer.jobs', {
        url: "^/jobs",
        templateUrl: '../partials/employer/jobs.html',
        controller: 'formController'
    })
    .state('job', {
        parent: 'employer.jobs',
        url: '/job/:jobId',
        //  abstract: true,
        controller: 'formController',
        onEnter: ['$uibModal', '$state', '$http', '$stateParams', function ($uibModal, $state, $http, $stateParams) {
            console.log('Open modal');

            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({

                templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                backdrop: false,
                windowClass: 'right fade',
                keyboard: true,
                controller: 'PostModalInstanceCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    job: function () {
                        return $stateParams.jobId;
                    },

                },
            }).result.finally(function () {
                        $state.go('employer.jobs');
                        console.log('job modal closed')
                    });
        }],
    })
    .state('system_matches', {
        parent: 'job',
        url: "/system_matches",
        controller: 'TController',
        views: {
            'job@': {
                templateUrl: '../partials/employer/system_matches.html',
            }
        }
    });
```

when I go to the `system_matches` state the URL looks good: `/employer#/jobs/job/1/system_matches` and the HTML is loading in the console but cant see the view.

the `job/:jobId` state is in a modal and from there I want to go to
the `system matches` state that is not in a modal.

I guess I need to add a `ui-view` div. my question is where do I need to put the `div` and how is it supposed to be named with the id parameter?

Comment: did you try to add:  template: '<ui-view/>'  , in job state?

Comment: @Tahiaji yes i have. i tried `<div ui-view=""></div>, <div ui-view="system_matches"></div> ,<ui-view/> `

Comment: @Tahiaji ok, so if i place `<div ui-view="job">` inside  my modal in `job` then i see the view in the modal. but i want it out of the modal and i cant seem to get it right

Comment: No, I mean place here:  .state('job', {
        template: '<ui-view/>' 
You can't use children with parent without any "ui-view". 
Try use one more abstract state(with empty ui-view), wich will be parent for both: system_matches and job